# how to implement ctrl+l for windows cmd?

Tags: windows, terminal, cmd, signals

In linux terminal as I give ctrl+L signal, terminal screen clears. since I am new in windows programming and I found that cls command is used to clear screen. How can I make ctrl+L signal in case of windows cmd to clear screen.

Comment: Rather than giving -1 .... one should also explain what is wrong and how to correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the cls command as a key shortcut will be more difficult.
There is something called AutoHotkey, you can try that and tell us if that helped you :)

[Click here to go to their website: AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone still stumbling upon this post, as it comes up first in Google search:

With the new Windows Terminal, you can go under Settings -> Actions -> Add new -> Clear buffer and set the hotkey you want.